# NextAuth Credential provider with apollo client?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Using NextAuth for GraphQL authentication with Apollo client in Next.js encounter the error

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';
import { useMutation, useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';
import { LOGIN_MUTATION } from '../../../graphql/mutations';
import { getErrorMessage } from '../../../lib';

export default (req, res) =>
    NextAuth(req, res, {
        providers: [
            Providers.Credentials({
                name: 'Credentials',
                credentials: {
                    identifier: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
                    password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
                },
                authorize: async (credentials) => {
                    const client = useApolloClient();
                    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState();
                    const [login] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION);

                    try {
                        await client.resetStore();
                        const { data: { login: { user, jwt } } } = await login({
                            variables: {
                                identifier: credentials.identifier,
                                password: credentials.password
                            }
                        });            
            
                        if (user) {
                            return user;
                        }
            
                    } catch (error) {
                        setErrorMsg(getErrorMessage(error));
                    }
                }
            })
        ],
        site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
        session: {
            jwt: true,
            maxAge: 1 * 3 * 60 * 60,
            updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
        },
        callbacks: {},
        pages: {
            signIn: '/auth/signin'
        },
        debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
        secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SECRET,
        jwt: {
            secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET,
        }
    });
```

I am wondering is there anyway to make this work with apollo?
Thank you for the helps.

Comment: You can't use React hooks in server-side code - they're meant to be used in your React components on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments rightfully pointed out, you can't use *hooks* in server-side code. You would have to create a new `ApolloClient` like this:

```
const client = new ApolloClient()
```

Then you can do queries like this for example:

```
const { data } = await client.query({
  query: "Your query",
  variables: { someVariable: true }
});
```

Best would be the to move the creation of the client to a separate external file as a function and import it in your server-side code whenever needed. Like done [here](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/nextjs-fullstack-serverless/apollo-client/) for example.

### Edit:

As @rob-art correctly remarks in the comments, for a [mutation][2], the code should look more like this:

```
const { data } = await client.mutate({
  mutation: "Your query",
  variables: { someVariable: true }
});
```

Comment: For information the code here is not totally correct. You should use "client.mutate" for a mutation and not ".query".
And the option is not anymore "query" but "mutation".

Comment: Can you link to the docs so that I can confirm and update?

Comment: Here is the documentation about this : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#functions
Their doc is not that clear anymore since the hooks are now the main use case.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how you would use this in the context of the rest of the async function?

Comment: @DrJ, to further elaborate, I would create the `ApolloClient` in a config file and import it somewhere in a file with `getInitialProps` and use `client.query` or `client.mutation` there. Hope this helps you

Comment: it's mutate and not mutation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will update the answer.